# Data set to experiment with multivariate count regression

Tags: regression, poisson-distribution, multivariate-regression

I have a model for predicting multiple count variables (multivariate count regression) given some covariates. Are there any publicly available datasets I could experiment with?

Comment: Can you clarify this a little bit? EG, have you developed a new type of analysis for this situation, &  want to compare how it behaves relative to standard methods on a known (perhaps classic) dataset?

Comment: yes, i have a new method and i would like to see how it performs on some real world data (classic/new). if you know some dataset(s) and could point to me that, it would be a big help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have money to pay for it, you can get exactly this kind of data from HLDI: http://www.iihs.org/research/hldi/composite

I don't know how much they charge or what their T&Cs are, but I know that it's good data and it's very comprehensive :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use insurance data. For example, in third party insurance for every policyholder "claim frequency" of different "claim types"  is a multivariate count.
In [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167668710001289) a multivariate Poisson regression model suggested by the authors.

Comment: I asked the authors but they said the data can't be shared due to restrictions. Do you know of any publicly available datasets?

Answer (score 0):

If you are a R user - For biological count data, you can have a look at the data in the R packages `mvabund`, `vegan`, `labdsv`.